# Is it ok to put a link <a> and an image <img> inside an h1 <h1>?

Tags: html, seo, standards, semantic-markup

Is it ok to put a link and an image inside an h1?

SEO wise, it makes sense but I'm debating whether its correct semantically and in regard of standards compliance.

Example

```
<h1>
  <a href="example.com" title="link to example.com">
    <img src="img.png" alt="example logo" />
    Example.com
  </a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

An `h1` tag is allowed to contain ["phrasing content"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html).  This means ["phrasing elements intermixed with normal character data"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content).  `a` and `img` tags [are both phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing).